# Laravel Dusk Error - Can't run default test

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to run default Laravel browser test, but I receive this error:

```
[...] $ php artisan dusk
PHPUnit 7.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 640 ms, Memory: 22.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"w3c":false,"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless","--window-size=1920,1080"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

/home/rere/laravel/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:297
/home/rere/laravel/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:144
/home/rere/laravel/tests/DuskTestCase.php:40
/home/rere/laravel/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:200
/home/rere/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:817
/home/rere/laravel/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:201
/home/rere/laravel/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:95
/home/rere/laravel/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:65
/home/rere/laravel/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:21

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Laravel version: 5.8

Laravel Dusk version: 5.8

I'm running Laravel on shared hosting (Linux).

Please, help me :(

UPDATE:

DuskTestCase.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        //static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox'
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://mywebsite.com/clients', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability( 
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        ); 
    }
}
```

LoginTest.php:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class LoginTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/login');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

P.S. My laravel public directory files are located under /public_html/clients directory. also, other laravel directories is located under /laravel dir.

Comment: It would probably help people help you if you shared some info about how you're running Laravel. For instance, are you using Valet? Homestead? Something else? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: @TravisNorthcutt I'm running Laravel on shared hosting (Linux)

Comment: @Finaffteam I know your question is a bit old. Have you managed it to work? Error states that your chromedriver is not running. So either uncomment line in prepare method of DuskTestCase.php or run your own updated chromedriver on port 9515.

Answer (score 0):

because of sandbox

update your drive like this:

```
protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox'
        ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: In your test class

Comment: I replaced localhost URL with my project URL, but I received the same error :(

Comment: Where is your DuskTestCase class ?

Comment: I'm sorry, there was another error after replacing driver() method with your code: `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in`. It seems that he don't like my URL

Comment: laravel/tests/DuskTestCase.php

Comment: If you can share your code in your question, i will help you, i can not imagine it :)

Comment: done - I added DuskTestCase.php and LoginTest.php files codes to my question. Ask me if you need something else, I just really need to solve this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have Chromium installed.

On Mac - with homebrew:

```
brew update

brew install --cask chromium
```

For Linux, try this:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```